# PHP Replace all characters with a symbol

Tags: php

I am trying to make an account generator with censured passwords, and I don't want to replace all characters with just 10 *'s. I want it to be like this:
if the password is 15 characters long, it will be replaced with 15 *'s. I tried to use this:

```
$censpass = preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9\']/', '*', $accounts[$i]['password']);
```

but as you might know, that doesn't work for !'s. How can I use preg_replace with *every single character* in PHP?
If someone doesn't understand:
I want this: "password123!"
to be replaced with this: "************" with the accurate length using preg_replace
If this exists somewhere else, please link it below, I tried to find this but I could only find how to replace some characters, like numbers only
Thank you :)

Comment: Try with `$censpass = preg_replace('/./', '*', $accounts[$i]['password']);`

Comment: I found something on a forum, you want to try this: `preg_replace("|.|","*",$mypassword);`

Comment: Awesome, thank you sir! Could you please explain how this works? Don't feel like you have to, but it would be very nice if you could at least link something :D

Comment: Both methods worked but the last message was ment for the first person, but could you link that forum please? :D

Answer (score 2):

For your goal I'd use a different approach, such as:

```
$encpass = str_pad('', strlen($accounts[$i]['password']), '*');
```

In fact, there is no need to use a regular expression (which is slow and resource consuming) just to generate a string the same length as another one.

Anyway, if you still want to use your solution, the correct regexp for your use case is simply a `.` such as:

```
$censpass = preg_replace('/./', '*', $accounts[$i]['password']);
```

Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.dot.php

Comment: I upvote because the str_pad, In my opinion they should change place in the answer.

Comment: I didn't see `str_pad` in your answer. I've deleted my answer that was about str_pad too. I think you really should put str_pad first, it's a better solution for this problem.